# How to send mail to @m.facebook.com with mail command line

Tags: linux, facebook, bash, email

I want to update my facebook status by sending an email to xxx@m.facebook.com. It works with Thunderbird or webmail. But with `mail` command of Linux, it does not send emails to xxx@m.facebook.com but works with emails to @gmail.com and others.

How can I send emails to xxx@m.facebook.com by using the `mail` or `sendmail` command?

Below is the log from mail.log:

```
Aug  4 04:02:34 s17773461 sm-mta[28533]: s7492YBE028533: from=<root@xxxx>, size=397, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201408040902.s7492YQJ028532@xxxx>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Aug  4 04:02:34 s17773461 sendmail[28532]: s7492YQJ028532: to=xxx@m.facebook.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30053, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s7492YBE028533 Message accepted for delivery)
Aug  4 04:02:34 s17773461 sm-mta[28535]: s7492YBE028533: to=<xxx@star.c10r.facebook.com>, ctladdr=<root@xxxx> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120397, relay=msgin.t.facebook.com. [173.252.113.23], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Aug  4 04:02:34 s17773461 sm-mta[28535]: s7492YBE028533: s7492YBE028535: DSN: Service unavailable
```

Comment: When "it works" from an e-mail client such as Thunderbird, are you using the same sender (ie. `root@`) or are you using a different account? It could be that `root` is simply rejected on the Facebook end.

Comment: Which e-mail server is your mail client configured to use? Are you using the `mail` command from that e-mail server? Or are you using the `mail` command from your client computer? It might be that Facebook is not accepting e-mails form clients that are not 'real' SMTP servers (for various reasons).